# How to pass a url as a hook menu argument

Tags: uri, routes

I need to send a url as a variable in path e.g.

2 arguments. The 2nd argument would need to be a url so http://www.blah.com. However, at the moment even if I use urlencode (which produces /http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blah.com) on the url when I visit that url, it reads it as

http://www.foo.com/arg1/http://www.blah.com which it obviously cant find as a page

```
 $items = array();
  $items['json/%/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'JSON Nodes',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'page arguments' => array(1,2),
    'page callback' => 'json_feed_page',
    'access callback' => TRUE
    //'file' =>
  );
  return $items;
```

Comment: if you pass it as normal query string it will work fine  `http://www.foo.com/arg1?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.blah.com`

Comment: and if your first `arg` is any indication, you could also access this via `post` instead of `get` and pass it along as a variable in the body of the request